# Percentage match between lists of strings (multiple intersections)

Tags: mysql

I have a table of ( list_id, string ) which contains lists of strings. I need to calculate percentage matched for list a against the other lists:

```
lista = ["a","b","c"] # Desired result:
list1 = ["b","c","g"] # 66%
list2 = ["g","h","i"] #  0%
```

The following gets the percentage complete against the first list by doing an intersection of the two lists.  How can I write this statement to match the first list against all the others: [ "66%", "0%", ]?

```
SELECT concat(round(( a.cnt1/b.cnt2 * 100 ),2),'%') AS percentage
FROM (SELECT count(string) AS cnt1 FROM tbl WHERE id=2 and (string) IN (SELECT string     FROM tbl where id=1)) a,
     (SELECT count(string) AS cnt2 FROM tbl WHERE id=1) b;
```

[Here is the SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c89012/1/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this suffice (one should normally leave out of the data tier presentational matters, such as rounding and concatenating with a `%` character):

```
SELECT   a.id, COUNT(b.string)/COUNT(*) AS percentage
FROM     tbl a LEFT JOIN tbl b ON b.id = 1 AND a.string = b.string
GROUP BY a.id
```

Depending on your requirements you may also wish to filter for `a.id <> b.id`.

If you absolutely need the described output format, you can place in a subquery and aggregate a second time with `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(ROUND(percentage*100,2),'%')) FROM (
  SELECT   COUNT(b.string)/COUNT(*) AS percentage
  FROM     tbl a LEFT JOIN tbl b ON b.id = 1 AND a.string = b.string
  GROUP BY a.id
) t
```

Comment: I knew I was going at it the wrong way. These two have taught me a lot, thanks.

Comment: @eggyal . . . A little known (used) feature of `group_concat()` is that it actually can take multiple arguments, obviating the need for a nested `concat()`.  Your second example could be written as:  `GROUP_CONCAT(ROUND(percentage*100,2), '%')`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Wow. Truly. That has made my day.  The manual hints at it, by showing `expr [, expr ...]` in the grammar and stating "*In MySQL, you can get the concatenated values of expression combinations.*", but really this feature could be a little more explicit.  Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
SELECT
  dest.id AS other_list,
  COUNT(dest.`string`)/(SELECT count(*) FROM tbl WHERE id=1)*100 as percentage_match
FROM
  tbl src
LEFT JOIN
  tbl dest
ON
  src.`string` = dest.`string` AND
  src.id = 1
WHERE
  dest.id != 1
GROUP BY
  dest.id
```

Just replace every occurence of `1` with the list, you want to compare against.

Lists with no match arent shown at all. (It also excludes matching 1 against 1, cause result would be 100% ofc.)

```
OTHER_LIST | PERCENTAGE_MATCH
2 | 66.6667 
4 | 33.3333
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c89012/49

It will work no matter how much elements a list has. Should even work if they are of different lengths. (but if a list `other` has - in your example speaking - the elements a,b,c,a,b,c it will return a match > 100%: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e6c90/1)

Comment: Thanks for the ON WHERE syntax for removing the origin id from the list. The way you wrote this also helps for intuitively grasping it for me.